How to extend daisyUi theme background color into the iOS safe area in a React project?
I am having hard time with setting the safe area background color on iOS devices in my project.
What I want to achieve:
The background color of the safe area to be updated dynamically to match the background color of the daisyUi theme on iOS devices in Brave and Safari browsers when the address bar is located on the bottom of the tab.
Some context info
The project is scaffolded via Vite -> React.
These are the attributes of my HTML tag:
<html id="html-element" lang="en" data-theme="light">
This is the meta tag nested in HTML tag:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
This is how I change the theme -> use the toggleTheme function located in my theme context file:
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext()

const ThemeContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light')

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    theme === 'light'
      ? setTheme('dark')
      : setTheme('light')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('#html-element').setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
  }, [theme])

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{
      theme,
      setTheme,
      toggleTheme
    }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export {ThemeContext, ThemeContextProvider}

Problem:
When the page loads, the data-set HTML attribute has value set to light as fallback (default value), and the safe area around the camera/sensor notch matches the background color of the light theme. But... when I switch to the dark theme, the background with toggleTheme function, the color of the safe-area doesn't update to match the dark theme despite the value of the data-set in HTML tag is updated correctly to dark. In consequence the safe area inset on top still has the light theme background color.
I have tried the following:

Add env() function and colors corresponding to theme background to the CSS file:

/* class to add padding based on safe area insets */
.padding-safe {
  padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
}

/* background color applied to the entire viewport */
.bg-light {
  background-color: rgba(250, 247, 245, 1);
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: rgba(29,35,42,1);
}


Apply the padding-safe class to body element in HTML file.

Conditionally change the background color using the above color classes in the top div wrapper on the App.jsx level based on the value of the theme state variable.

I've also tried with inline CSS in the HTML file by manipulating DOM. Function setSafeAreaBg() returns the RGBA color value as a string based on the theme state variable:


document.querySelector('#body-element').setAttribute('style', setSafeAreaBg())
My observations:
In the MDN docs the env() CSS function is used to set padding for safe area insets, I've tried to use this to assist with setting the background color for those insets. My approach could be totally wrong, and perhaps that is why it doesn't work.
TIA
